# magento 2 extension attribute value is coming null

Tags: magento2, plugin, extension-attributes

I an creating a customer address attribute using this code

```
<?php

namespace Ansh\CustomAddressAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'sms', [
            'label' => 'Mobile (Courier text notifications)',
            'input' => 'text',
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table ::TYPE_TEXT,
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'sms')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
                'customer_address',
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

and its visible in my front end on last

[image]

also i added extension attribute  using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="sms" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I am trying to get extension attribute's value in my plugin

as following

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="sms_address_save_plugin" type="Ansh\CustomAddressAttribute\Plugin\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

but when i am using getSms i am getting null

```
<?php

namespace Ansh\CustomAddressAttribute\Plugin;


class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{
    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();

        $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
        var_dump($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getSms());die;
        if ($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes) {
            $sms = $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getSms();
            $shippingAddress->setSms($sms);
        }

    }
}
```

whats wrong i am doing 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout.js code reads and sends `extension_attributes` in the ajax request.

First, you need to fetch the saved attribute value in the js file.

please check

1. `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`
2. `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js`
3. `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/select-shipping-address.js`

for your reference

from there via ajax request your address data will be passed in the server-side (PHP) code.

otherwise, you will not get the data on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

you have created a customer address attribute to save on a quote address entity.
I suggest creating an attribute for the quoted address first.

Then, the extension attribute should be on the interface `\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface`

Comment: Then will I get input in shipping form?

Comment: the most important is to change the extension interface in the extension_attributes file.. where you persist the data is possibly not the most important thing to change.. If you give it a go, if it does not work, I am happy to dig more

Comment: hi thanks for help but i am not able to find Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface in vendor or genrated on what basis are you suggesting

Comment: ok, will take a look but that might have to be tomorrow, thanks for your update

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Hi to all I have got a similar issue in my Magento 2.4.3 environment, in which I cannot find vendor/magento/module-checkout/ folder and all of its content. Any suggestions?